# I want convert date into Month

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have dates and wanting to convert dates into month like Jan Feb, I have written the code `FORMAT_DATE('%B', DATE(PARSE_DATE ('%m-%d-%Y', Date))) AS month_of_date`

| Date | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1/20/2024 |  |
| 1/21/2024 |  |
| 1/26/2024 |  |
| 2/1/2024 |  |
| 2/2/2024 |  |
| 2/2/2024 |  |

Comment: Please only use the tag for the database you are using. Which data type has your date column?

Comment: For MySQL, you can use `date_format(your_date,'%b')`

Answer (score 0):

I need more info regarding the source data type and DBMS you use. But, I assume you have field that has string/varchar data type and want to get the month name using MySQL. Here is the code:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%b') AS Month
```

For trial running, I have created [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/RsfzDavQ) for you.

Comment: I am using sqlite

Comment: [SQLite does not support month names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181123/date-formatting-from-sqlite-query), sadly. You will have to convert it to a month name either using a lookup table, a case statement, or a switch on the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL, you can use:

```
substring(DATENAME(MONTH,'2024-01-25'), 1,3)
```

With this, you will get the First 3 letters of the month name.
Like for JANUARY - JAN

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).